# Array Diff not finding array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

Ive got a function that is supposed to compare 2 arrays. Array diff is sending a warning that the first argument isn't an array.... also open to any better ways to write this function. I was just kind of winging it on this one. Thanks!

```
function changeLog(){
include('../includes/conn.inc.php'); 
//select object and make an array with each current value 
    $stmt = $mysql->prepare ("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $_POST['id']);
    $OK = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result(
        $id,
        $name,
        $created,
        $edited,
        $owner
    );
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $array1 = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'owner' => $owner 
        );}
    $stmt->close(); 

//$array1 now holds current values for each field
//now grab the post values from the update and stick them into array2

        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $owner= $owner;

    $array2 = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'owner' => $owner 
        );

//$array2 now holds post values for each field in the update
//check the arrays and spit out the differences

    $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
//strip the values and just output the array keys

$dbInput =(array_keys($result));

        foreach($dbInput as $i){
            $owner=  'use'.$_SESSION['i'];
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO history (id, created, edited, owner, parent, body) 
                    VALUES (NULL,NOW(),NOW(),?,?,?)';
            $stmt = $mysql->stmt_init();
            if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) { 
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $owner, $_POST['id'], $i);
                $OK = $stmt->execute();}
                $stmt->close(); 

        }
}// end changeLog
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? insert new rows and update existing ones, or what?

Comment: It inserts rows into a seperate table that has the names of the changed fields and elements of the user object of the person who changed it... that part is fine. The function actually works fine but its throwing a warning that array diff and array keys arent getting an array for the first argument and i cant see why they wouldnt be.

Comment: if the while loop runs zero times, then array1 is never assigned.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=? - this is obviously sometimes returning zero results. Can it ever return more than one result? Your code will set array1 to the last of many, or not set it at all.

Comment: thanks man, but its running. I tried after the first stmt close running print_r(array1) and ive got values. thats why its puzzling me. It can only return 1 result. id is a primary key auto inc. Also while testing ive hardcoded an id that does exist for sure and still the same issue. However, just in case it is noteworthy, sometimes name will have a value but owner will return null. but always at least one returns a value

Comment: Then I think your while is confusing syntax, an if would be better. Sorry, the ONLY way array1 might not be an array is if the loop isnt executed.

Comment: `$array1` is being overwritten on each iteration, so it'll only ever be populated with the last row returned by your query (change to `$array1[]`).. that said, I don't know why `array_diff` would say the first argument isn't an array, unless the query returned no results :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try coding it a bit more like this and see if it tells you anything:

```
if($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
   $array1 = array('name' => $name, 'owner' => $owner);
   //$array1 now holds current values for each field 
   //now grab the post values from the update and stick them into array2
   $name= $_POST['name'];
   $owner= $owner;
   $array2 = array('name' => $name,         'owner' => $owner          );
  //$array2 now holds post values for each field in the update 
  //check the arrays and spit out the differences
  $result = array_diff($array1, $array2); 
 // ...
} else {
      echo "no result returned";
}
```

Comment: thanks dude, after some trial and error i think something is def wrong with the post array for id.

Comment: That could make the query fail, so definately :)